# Removing path of a connected graph.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path, graph-connectivity

I bumped into this question in an old exercice sheet :

> Let $ G = (V,E) $ be a connected graph with minimum degree $ \delta(G) = k \geq 2$. Prove that there exist a path $P = x_1x_2...x_k$ such that $G \setminus P $ is also connected $G \setminus P$ is the same as $G[V\setminus (x_1,x_2,...x_k)]$.

I wanted to prove it by induction but even for the cas $k=2$ I didn't know where to begin.

I thought maybe using the fact that in a graph with minimum degree k there always exist a cycle of length $k+1$ but then I have no idea how to show that it's possible to remove a part of the cycle.

Thank you for your help

Comment: $k = 2$ means that every vertex has at least two neighbours. I guess this means that the graph must include a cycle. Hence, you'll easily find a path $P = x_1x_2$ such that $G -P$ is still connected. You need to choose your vertices from this specific cycle and remove them. (but I am not entirely sure)